# Name for characters not physically in a story

Tags: characters, terminology

Is there a technical name for a character that is mentioned by name but is never present in a story?

For example, a parent who is discussed by their children and still alive but has no screen time whatsoever?

Is "estranged" or "offscreen" character good enough?

Comment: Related on ELU: [A novel/book equivalent of the term off-screen](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/236448/191178)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unseen Character

> s there a technical name for a character that is mentioned by name but is never present in a story?

A character that is discussed, but does not appear in the work is called an "**[unseen character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unseen_character)**".

From wikipedia: "An unseen character in theatre, comics, film, or television, or **silent character** in radio or literature, is a character that is mentioned but not directly known to the audience, but who advances the action of the plot in a significant way, and whose absence enhances their effect on the plot."

The article also uses the terms: **offstage character** and **invisible character** which may have slight nuances in how they have been dramatized, but are generally interchangeable (an *invisible character* may be implied to be present, voiced from offstage or reacted to by other characters in pantomime).

> Is "estranged" or "offscreen" character good enough?

I would not use these terms.

*Estranged* is a *relationship status* to other characters. It does not imply the audience's experience.

*Offscreen* (originally *offstage*) is a production (stage) direction, and implies a *temporary* condition. Characters and objects that have previously been offstage can be moved onstage, and back again.

In the case of film, an offscreen direction can literally last a few frames within a scene where the subject is present but the camera is pointed at something else, as in 2-person dialog where one character's response is heard "offscreen".

Comment: I've also heard such characters be referred to as "ghosts" but this might be confusing if you're working in a horror setting.

Answer (score 2):

Narrative Designer here,

This might be specific to video games, but I generally use "Reference-Only Character" if the NPC isn't planned to actually appear in the game.